# Scroll a JScrollBar in WindowBuilder Pro

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jscrollpane, windowbuilder

I'm building a `JDialog` with `WindowBuilder` Pro for Eclipse and I have put a `JPanel` in that's surrounded by a `JScrollPane` which does allow me to scroll through the `JPanel`. But now What I want to do is add components to it (e.g `JTextFields` and `JLabels`) but I can only add to the part of the `JPanel` that's `JPanel` that's out of this range is inaccessible...

Is there a way to make the `JScrollPane` scroll down within WindowBuilder's Design view so that the `JPanel` moves up so that I can place the requirements inside it?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to place components directly into the Component view of the design tab, so you should be able to add JTextFields and JLabels to the JPanel this way